# problema lazy loading EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

si yo hago por ejemplo una select de todos los campos, puedo leer el nombre de la ciudad?? porque me da error como que "ciudades" es null

```
List<Clientes> lista= (from C in db.Clientes select C).ToList();
```

EDIT: la excepción que tengo es

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Dado que tengo el proyecto separado en capas.. cuando llego a la capa de presentación con mi lista de clientes, al usar Lazy Loading no puedo acceder a las ciudades desde esta capa porque no puede conectarse a la bd, eso es lo que entiendo.. no se como manejarlo entonces

Capa de presentación:

```
//parte del codigo de la capa de presentación..
List<Clientes> clientes = ClientesCN.listarClientes();
foreach(var cliente in clientes)
{
 //otros campos
 txtCiudad.text=cliente.Ciudades.nombre;//en esta linea arroja error  porque Ciudades es null
}
```

alguna sugerencia?

saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias usar el `Include()` para cargar la propiedad de navegacion a las Ciudades

Entonces quedaria

```
List<Clientes> lista= db.Clientes.Include(x=> x.Ciudades).ToList();
```

Esto se explica aqui

[Cargar entidades relacionadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)